# White screen before loading Window WPF

Tags: wpf

Why am i getting **white screen** when i try to load some other window from a window by

```
window.show()
```

method. Is it inherent property of **WPF** or there is a way to make that annoying **white flash** go away ?

**More information**

in window_loaded i have some calculation to do, but even after  putting calculation in

**BackgroundWorker** and making busy indicator from "**ExtendedWPF toolkit** also doesnot help as busy indicator shown only after all UI is loaded and white screen problem stays ?

Shouldn't microsoft should have something to not to show whitescreen before loading ?

Comment: Hmm, it depends whether and if so, what you're doing during initialization. So how about some more information?

Comment: Sometimes the hardware (graphicscard) or the drivers can get in the way because WPF uses these extensively. Make sure they (relatively) new.

Comment: If the busy indicator is shown after the UI is loaded, then I'm guessing you are running a lot of stuff on the UI thread.

Comment: Does it also happen when you do absolutely nothing in loaded events and/or in the background? Try making a minimal representative example.

Comment: @Erno apparently yes for shorter period but yes

Comment: In that case I suspect the graphics-card, its drivers or perhaps even the OS. Make sure they are up-to-date.

Comment: is there no way to render UI before hand and do all loading event calculation later